# Copy value of one column to another column, but only where fields have no value MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have looked for an answer to this and can't find what I need.  I dare not try anything I have made up...

I want to copy the value of one column (column a) to another column to (column b) but I only want this to happen to fields within column b that have no current value.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: no current value as in "empty string", or no value at all as in "null"?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
UPDATE table1
   SET b = a
 WHERE b IS NULL
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8896/1)** demo

If `b` is of `VARCHAR` type and you consider empty strings also as having no value then you can do

```
UPDATE table1
   SET b = a
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(COALESCE(b, '')) = 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a384d/1)** demo

Comment: Probably second method is gonna force a full table scan, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `UPDATE` your table and set your columnb same as column a only where column b is null

```
UPDATE table
SET columnb = columna
WHERE columnb IS NULL
```

If your column have empty strings just use `WHERE columnb = ''`

Answer (score 0):

So like:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ColumnB = ColumnA
WHERE ColumnB IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET row1 = row2 
WHERE row2 IS NULL OR row2 = ''
```

This will consider both NULL and empty rows.

Otherwise - just post what you made up, so we can verify it.